# Function key to toggle Wifi on Dell XPS does not work with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, dell, xps, rfkill

I've got a Dell XPS 9360 and updated to Ubuntu 18.04. However now the key to toggle Wifi and Bluetooth (Fn+Print) does not work anymore within Gnome.

Outside of Gnome the key works, when pressing Fn+Print on the console, "rfkill" successfully shows the state of "phy0" being toggled between soft blocked and soft unblocked. The key also works on GDM, however as soon as I logon it stops working. I found the following Gnome bug (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=788683) which states that Gnome blocks the kernel from recognizing the key press, but is unable to handle the key press on its own. The bug claims that all you need to to is update xkeyboard-config to contain the patch from https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100970. However the version which contains this patch is 2.24 and it doesn't exist in Ubuntu.

When I try to manually apply the patch to /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev and /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet and reboot, nothing changes. The function key still doesn't work.

Is there any way how I can this key working again, or at least prevent Gnome from blocking it?